Grouping only the numbers in between any URL
I want to group the number in between the URLs using regex. How to do it? Here are the example below -
URL1: https://www.metabo.com/uk/en/accessories/sawing/circular-saw-blades/precision-cut-wood/saw-blade-precision-cut-wood-classic-160x20-z36-wz-10-b-628659000.html
Output: 628659000
URL2: https://www.metabo.com/uk/en/tools/others/glue-guns/hk-18-ltx-20-600797840-cordless-hot-glue-gun.html
Output: 600797840
Note: Need to use only one regex which will work on both the URLs.
Thanks in advance.
I have tried with this following regex-
([0-9]+).html

It is working on first URL but not in 2nd one.

You want the last sequence of numbers in the URL?

You need to think about what you are trying to capture. What you tried is: give me any number followed by .html. In the second example the number you are looking for is not followed by .html. So what do you want to find? A number that has 9 digits? A number that starts with a 6? If you know that, you can write the right regular expression (or let us help you with that)

What is the exact logic? How do you know that you want 600797840 and not 18?

Try: \d+(?=\D*). A number followed only by non-digits.

I want the number that comes before ".html" and starts after "-" .
